# SQL Server Query with PHP return allways Null

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I Try To Query SL Server Using PHP,
but return allways Null,
here my code

```
<?php
  $serverName = "10.xxx.xxx.xxx";
  $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "sa","PWD" => "****","Database" =>  "Database");  
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
  if( $conn ) {
   echo('Connected');
  $tsql="select top 1 * from master_site";
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);    
     if ( $stmt )    
         {    
                    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn,$tsql);
                    $next_result = sqlsrv_next_result($result);
                    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result); 
                    echo($row["logdata"]);
                    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);
            }


 //echo ($data);
  }else{
  echo('Error');
 }
?>
```

i know this is simple question and probably duplicate with other
but i thik i allready tried all solution but until tody still no luck for me
plese help me guys

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the following:

- Don't execute `sqlsrv_query()` twice
- Don't execute `sqlsrv_next_result()`. The first result returned by a query is active after the `sqlsrv_query()` call.

You may try with the next example, based on your code:

```
<?php
    $serverName = "10.xxx.xxx.xxx";
    $connectionInfo = array("UID" => "sa","PWD" => "****","Database" =>  "Database");  
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn) {
        echo('Connected');
        $tsql = "select top 1 * from master_site";
        $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);    
        if ($stmt === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result); 
        echo($row["logdata"]);
        sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    } else {
        echo('Error');
    }
?>
```